# There's a way to change PART titles only in the TOC so that I can put author's names on the TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, parts, author

I would like to modify TOC so that the part "V, postproduction" appears with the author like this: "V, posproduction (Simone Corelli)". There's a simple way like the one in the captions where in the square bracket you can put a different description (usually shorter)?

Comment: Yes: The optional part of a sectioning command goes to the TOC: `\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part[postproduction (Simone Corelli)]{postproduction}
\end{document}`. Where does the `,` comma come from? Is it needed?

Comment: @cicada no need for the comma. Your answer is perfect. I have also added \textnormal{\emph{(Simone Corelli}} to a better visual effect. SIMPLE!